# Can I develop Windows Phone 7.1 apps using Windows Phone 8 SDK?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Basically, if I download the WP8 SDK, can I develop WP7 apps with it?

Or can I only create WP8 apps?

Thanks.

Comment: We are not here to do your research/work. The question does not seem to be a specific coding related problem.

Comment: It's a valid question. I only discovered the answer having installed both the SDK and VS 2013. It's not clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, you'll have to download the seperate SDKs and use the workaround here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/02/29/10274694.aspx, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Phone 8 SDK supports 7.1 projects but only in Visual Studio 2012.

Only 8.0 is available in Visual Studio 2013, however you can still use the 2012 Express IDE installed with the SDK to develop apps for both.

Answer (score 1):

No, the APIs are not the same.

look here and download what you need 
http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk